# Strange behavior scrolling in LongListSelector using data binding - Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, data-binding, longlistselector

I have an app where I save the user's contacts in a local Database, then bind this contacts in a LongListSelector using ObservableCollection to update the UI (when a new item is add or deleted).

But I'm having a strange behavior when the ObservableCollection is changed...
The item is add to the UI correctly, but after this, when I scroll fast, a blank space appears in the middle of the list.
Then I found out that, apparently, the list is cutting some items...

I was testing with a list of 140 items (strings), having at least one item starting with each alphabetic letter.

When this problem happens, I saw that after items with C letter, started the items with P letters (D to O disappeared!).

Does anybody can tell me what is happening?

I bind the items on LongListSelector this way:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanelContatos" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <Grid x:Name="gridContatos" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,2,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,12" >
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" TextChanged="TbxSearch_TextChanged" LostFocus="TbxSearch_LostFocus" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
        </Grid>

        <phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" x:Name="llsContacts" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectionChanged="llsContacts_SelectionChanged" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem local:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="true">
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding COLUMN_NAME, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="28" Margin="77,0,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=COLUMN_NUMBER, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="17" Margin="77,33,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>       
    </Grid>

    <!-- more 2 grids with contents -->
</Grid>
```

CS:

public ObservableCollection list;

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    list = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(GetDataFromDatabase);
    llsContacts.DataContext = list;
}
```

When I insert or remove something on DataBase, I alter on the list too:

```
list.Add(newData);
```

Am I doing something worng??

Reading this article: [Frame rate counters in Windows Phone](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/), I noticed that when this problem happens, some of the numbers that are on the side of the screen when debugging, stops changing...

They stops like this:

User Interface Thread FPS: 000
Texture Memory Usage: 007181
Surface Counter: 050
Intermediate Texture Counter: 002

Does this numbers means something?

Comment: Did you find the solution for it ?

Comment: Yes, actually the problem was not with the list. I was using an animation on the same screen in a wrong way, that caused a lot of memory use, and caused this problem on the list.

Comment: thanks :) let me check my code again